# Is there any way to change font size after CreateFont?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to change font size depending on the size of main window. So, I create font in OnCreate() and I get window size in OnSize() and want to change only font size in there. I think OnSize() is not good place to create font. Am I right? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the values associated with an `HFONT`. You would have to destroy it and create a new `HFONT` with the desired values each time.

Comment: Then, do I have to place CreateFont in OnSize()? Whenever window size changes, CreateFont is called. Is there better place to put CreateFont?

Comment: Yes, `OnSize` is probably the most appropriate place.